# How to add new host to flynn if discover token is not known?

Tags: flynn

Documentation tells us to add it using -with --discover token. but how do I find discover token? cluster was created a while ago and I can not find what discover token was used.

I tried to generate new discover token on leader, and init new host to that, but that did not work. no messages either.

Answer (score 0):

try typing `history` command in the terminal and grep it

`history | grep discovery`